# Server can't reply to client's UDP EndPoint

Tags: vb.net, sockets, udp

I have a UDP client/server app where the client sends periodic messages to the server and the server replies. This works fine unless the server is restarted while the client is running. After that point, client messages still reach the server, but server replies are not received the client.

When the server receives the message from the client, it gets its EndPoint and uses that when replying, so it should be replying to the right IP and UDP port.

```
Private Sub ReceiveUDP(ByVal AR As IAsyncResult)
        Dim Sender As EndPoint = CType(New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0), EndPoint)
        Dim BytesRead As Integer = UDPSocket.EndReceiveFrom(AR, Sender)
        'Following code snipped
End Sub
```

The server responds:

```
SendUDP(Sender, "CONNECTED")
```

and calls these subs:

```
Private Sub SendUDP(ByVal EndPoint As EndPoint, Message As String)
        Dim Data() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Message)
        UDPSocket.BeginSendTo(Data, 0, Data.Length, SocketFlags.None, EndPoint,
              New AsyncCallback(AddressOf UDPCallback), EndPoint)
End Sub 

Public Sub UDPCallback(ByVal AR As IAsyncResult)
        UDPSocket.EndSend(AR)
End Sub
```

Am I not replying to the EndPoint correctly? Thanks.

Comment: In order for this question to get answered by the right people, you should tag it with the name of the language you are using in your example code snippets.

Comment: What is the value of `Sender` in `SendUDP(Sender, "CONNECTED")`?

Comment: "Sender" is the Remote EndPoint of the client machine that sent the UDP message to the server. Looking at it in the Visual Studio watch window, it contains the IP address and port number of the client machine that sent the message. You can use the Remote Endpoint to reply to the client after a message is sent, but it doesn't seem to work for subsequent sessions after the server has been restarted.